# Send a .png file using python cgi

Tags: python, apache-flex, cgi

How can I send a .png file using python cgi to a flex application?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which part do you want help with flex or python cgi - server or client? If you've figured out the cgi part, it's the same in Flex or html - just use the cgi url

Comment: Since you say 'send an image': you wanna display it in an image control or load it in to a byte array for processing? Either case, you can just use the CGI url as the `src` attribute. As for the CGI part, you should parse the url and get the image path, then read the file, write it to the response with a content-type header set to `image/png`: I'm not familiar how to do this in CGI, so wait for someone to come with some code.

Answer (score 3):

The Python/CGI side of your question can be as simple as something like this, if you just need to send an existing image:

```
import sys

# Send the Content-Type header to let the client know what you're sending
sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n')

# Send the actual image data
with open('path/to/image.png', 'rb') as f:
    sys.stdout.write(f.read())
```

If, on the other hand, you're dynamically creating images with, say, [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), you can do something along these lines:

```
import sys
import Image, ImageDraw # or whatever

sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n')

# Dynamically create an image
image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))
# ... etc ...

# Send the image to the client
image.save(sys.stdout, 'PNG')
```